# Relative Sizing with a Fixed Position

Tags: css, html, resize, dreamweaver

The best example I can find of what I'm trying to achieve with my current website project is the amazon homepage.
     I want the width of a banner on my page to be 100% of the browser width, but I don't need it to resize when the window is resized. In addition, I would like the entire page to not resize and instead cut off/have scroll bars. 
     The banner is located at the top of the page, has a hi-res image as the background, and contains my nav bar as well as some text. 
     What would be the best method to set the size of my percentage based divs relative to screen resolution? Is there a way to set the size of my images without using percentages for size? (div width = screen width).
     I'm having issues with divs containing text not resizing correctly, the text gets jumbled when the browser is resized. I'm using html5 and css with dreamweaver cs6.

Comment: and why wouldn't you just pick a fixed width for the whole site, if you don't actually want it to be responsive?

Comment: Your problem is hard to understand this way and reproduce. Please, share an example or fiddle.

Comment: andi - because I want the banner at the top of my page to fill the width of the user's screen but show the entirety of the image set as the background. The image dimensions are 3096 x 1098, I guess it would be better to just make the site fixed and hope their screen isn't wider than 3096 px

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

The header re-sizes but the content stays at a fixed size when page resizes:

https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/zopnqxry/4/

```
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="body">
<div class="left">

</div>
<div class="right">

</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{margin: 0; overflow: scroll}
.header{width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: lightblue;}
.body{width: 400px; height: 600px; background-color: lightgreen; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
.left, .right{width: 50%; height: 200px; float: left;}
.left{background-color: blue;}
.right{background-color: red;}
```